# mathematical rules for background-blend-mode

Tags: html, css

in order to implement some CSS functions in WebGL, I am trying to understand precisely their implementations.

Currently my problem concerns the mix-blend-mode.

```html
<div
    style="
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-blend-mode: difference;
      background-image:
        linear-gradient(
          rgba(0,255,153,0.7), rgba(0,255,153,0.7)),
        linear-gradient(
          rgba(255,0,51,0.4), rgba(255,0,51,0.4));
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
      "
  ></div>
```

color picker on screenshot  is:

[image]

> 102/255 = 0.4
> 179/255 = 0.7
> 99/255 =  0.388...

**I apply the theory explained here**

https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing/#blending

**...as I thought I understood it :**

```
Cb = (1,0,0.2)  and ab = 0.4   
Cs = (0,1,0.6)  and as = 0.7  

Cm = | Cb - Cs | = (1,1,0.4) { I'm not sure at all...}
we replace Cs by Cm :
Cs = (1,1,0.4)

co = Cs * as + (0,0,0)*ab*(1-as)
co = (1,1,0.4) * 0.7
co = (0.7 , 0.7 , 0.28)

ao = as + ab * (1-as)
ao = 0.7 + 0.4 * (1-0.7)
ao = 0.82
```

**....I can't find the theoretical calculation corresponding to the result of the screenshot**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blending

[image]

> ao x Co = as x (1-ab) x Cs + as x ab x B(Cb,Cs) + (1-as) x ab x Cb
> In my example :
> as=0.7
> ab = 0.4
> Cs=(0,1,153/255)
> Cb=(1,0,51/255)
> B(Cb,Cs) = Abs( 1-0 , 0-1 , (153-51)/255 ) = (1,1,0.4)
> so,
> ao x Co=0.7 x 0.6 x (0,1,153/255) + 0.7 x 0.4 x (1,1,0.4)  + 0.3 x 0.4 x (1,0,51/255)
> **ao*Co= ( 0.4 , 0.7 , 0.388)**